# Why Sun Radius is 0.0003 in M_Sky_Panning_Clouds2 (UE4 SkySphere Material)?

Tags: shader, unreal-engine4

UE4 SkySphere Material Question:
Why Sun Radius is 0.0003 in M_Sky_Panning_Clouds2 ?

[image: this is sun part of M_Sky_Panning_Clouds2]

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to click the Param node and edit the float value in the inspector.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/Editor/